# How to write text formatting in translated strings with Qt / Qt Linguist?

Tags: qt, internationalization, translation

Part of my source code displays text in English that uses common text formatting characters (E.g.: `\n`: `"This is my\nstring"`). When I call `lupdate` and open the .ts file in Qt Linguist, it correctly displays the formatted text in the source text preview space (so without the `\n` or else).

The problem is that, when I translate the string and put the formatting characters in the translation and run the application with the translation file, my app reads the special characters as normal ones!

How may I overcome this problem? How can I put the necessary text formatting so the translation procedure don't generate such kind of bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you translate your app, you should press Enter, where you see \n.
For example,you see this string in source code
This is my\nstring
In linguist you should write:
This is my[here press Enter]
string.

When you run app with this translation, you'll see that all good.
I hope, it helps.